# PIL/pillow: Unable to use putpixel() to change a pixel value

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to run:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
os.chdir('C:\\.....FOLDER.....')
catIm = Image.open('zophie.png')

width, height = catIm.size
quartersizedIm = catIm.resize((int(width / 4), int(height / 4)))

for x in range(0,102,1):
    for y in range(0,136,1):
        quartersizedIm.putpixel((x,y),(0,0,255,255))
            quartersizedIm.putpixel((x,y))=quartersizedIm.putpixel((x,y))+100
```

I'm unable to change pixels to fixed value, getting the error:

> cant assign to function call

Comment: Sorry, am new to stack. still learning to format

Comment: If you would look at the full error instead of the snip you posted, you'd know it was complaining about `quartersizedIm.putpixel((x,y))=`.